# How to rotate around some coordinate axis in camera view?

Tags: transforms

Apparently, if I press <kbd>R</kbd> rotation occurs in the plane of view. How do I rotate around some coordinate axis in camera view?

Comment: Go into camera view and hit R

Comment: And I will rotate in view plain

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify your question, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @Dims Just press 'r' and then the letter for the desired axis e.g. x, y or z? Is that what you mean?

Comment: What are you attempting to rotate?  An object, the camera itself?  Which coordinate axis?  global, local, custom?   And by camera view are you referring to the view through the camera?  Also, http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Rking/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Transform_Orientations#Custom_Orientations

Answer (score 1):

In the 3D view header change the *Transform Orientation* to *View*.
[image: Transform Orientation]
Then when you want to rotate something around one of the other axises of the current view just press <kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd>. The *Z* axis in view mode is how it will rotate with out any axis constraints.

Answer (score 0):

After you press <kbd>R</kbd>, press <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, or <kbd>X</kbd> to rotate around the `z`, `y`, or `x` axis.
Or you can <kbd>MMB [image: MMB]</kbd> and drag the mouse to the desired axis.